# How to obtain all available EC2 key pairs in boto3

Tags: amazon-ec2, aws-sdk, boto3

How to obtain all available EC2 key pairs in boto3?

```
import boto3

ec2 = boto3.resource('ec2')
```

Answer (score 5):

```
import boto3

client = boto3.client('ec2', 'ap-southeast-2')

keypairs = client.describe_key_pairs()
```

See: [boto3 describe_key_pairs() documentation](https://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/ec2.html#EC2.Client.describe_key_pairs)

Please note that, for security reasons, you cannot download the keypairs themselves. You'll simply be given their name and fingerprint.